# use gh cli to create issues list

Tags: shell, github-cli

I am trying to create an array of opened issue numbers from GitHub. I am using the following command to pull all the opened issue numbers we have in a specific repo and label:

`issueNumList=$(gh issue list -R <repo name> -l "label" | cut -f1)`

the problem is that I am unable to read from issueNumList as a list (obviously).
I tried making it into an array by running this command, but it gets only the first number:

`IFS=' \n' read -ra issuesArray <<< "${issueNumList[0]}"`

I tried changing this command a few times but I don't see any difference in the output. this is the output I get:

```
$ echo ${issueNumList[0]}
1684 1683 1681 1680 1679 1678 1677 1676 1675 1674 1673 1672 1671 1670 1669 1668 1667
$ echo ${issueNumList[@]}
1684 1683 1681 1680 1679 1678 1677 1676 1675 1674 1673 1672 1671 1670 1669 1668 1667
$ echo "${issueNumList[0]}"
1684
1683
1681
1680
1679
1678
1677
1676
1675
1674
1673
1672
1671
1670
1669
1668
1667
$ echo ${issuesArray[@]}
1684
$ echo ${issuesArray[0]}
1684
$ echo ${issuesArray[1]}

$ echo ${issuesArray[2]}
```

from these outputs, I understand that there is only one spot in the `issueNumList` and `issuesArray` and from the third output I think it means that there is \n at the end of each number.

Comment: Paste ex. `echo ${issueNumList[@]}` into http://shellcheck.net . Please read [ask]. Do you have a question to ask?

Comment: how to turn the output of the first command into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to turn the output of the first command into an array?

`issueNumList` is not an array - no sense to use `[0]` on it.

`read` reads up until a newline. Specify a delimiter to zero byte, then you can read a newline-separated list. Also `'\n'` is twocharacters `\` and `n`, it's not a newline, you can use ANSI C quoting in `$'\n'` to get a newline.

```
issueNumList=$(gh issue list -R <repo name> -l "label" | cut -f1)
IFS=$' \n' read -d '' -r -a issuesArray <<<"$issueNumList"
```

but *the way* to read lines in bash into an array is `readarray`:

```
readarray -t issuesArray <<<"$issueNumList"
```

To debug variable contents use `declare -p`, like `declare -p issuesArray` or `declare -p issueNumList`.

Comment: which package has readarray? brew doesn't find it

Comment: bash >4.something has readarray, macos has very old bash

Comment: unfortunately that's what we use on our images

Comment: You can always `tr '\n' ' '` or `paste -sd' '` and read space-separated list, or just ignore best -practice and use word splitting.

Comment: just for future reference, what @KamilCuk offered worked perfectly on my mac, but on the debian image (version stretch-slim) it didn't because of the ```-d``` (even though it's an option). had to remake the 2 lines into:
```issueNumList=$(gh issue list -R <repo name> -l "label" | cut -f1 | tr '\n' ',')
IFS=$' ,' read -r -a issuesArray <<< "$issueNumList"```